# How to pass results of urllib2.urlopen to a function

Tags: python

WHen I run this I get the following error - TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Can someone please tell me how I can pass the results of function getURL() to function romid()?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial, time, os, decimal, csv, urllib2, socket
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.cElementTree import parse

romidList = []
    id = '{http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver}ROMId'
    owd= '{http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver}owd_DS18B20'

def getURL():
    f = urllib2.urlopen(''.join(['http://', '169.254.1.2', '/details.xml']))
    #add the next line
    return f

def romid():
    f = getURL()
    for x in parse(f).findall(owd):

        romID = x.find(id) 
        romID = romID.text

        if romID not in romidList:

            romidList.append(romID)

        print romidList

romid()
```

Comment: you need to return `f` in your getURL function

Answer (score 2):

well...have you considered using the `return` statement in your `getURL` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NoneType found because your not returning anything in your getURL() function, you are just declaring the variable f, not returning it

Comment: OK I added the return f as shown in my code but I still get the error. If I replace "f = getURL()" in function romid() with "f = urllib2.urlopen(''.join(['http://', '169.254.1.2', '/details.xml']))" it works fine. I must be missing something but I can't figure out what. Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What were you passing to the urlopen function before it was `.join(['http://', '169.254.1.2', '/details.xml'])`

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure I understand your question. If I remove the getURL() function and move the line "f = urllib2.urlopen(''.join(['http://', '169.254.1.2', '/details.xml']))" to the romid() function I do not get the error.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late; I am having difficulty finding the solution because the host is apparently down `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>`